# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: net.roseindia.model.Article

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc

i am trying to run a sample project from [Rose India Here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-and-hibernate3-example-part2.html)  but i am getting the exception :

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: net.roseindia.model.Article

I have tried all the solutions i found, one of the accepted solution is:

Using::: import javax.persistence.Entity; but no success.

One of the solution is about persistence class but as the sample project does not contain persistence class (as i am new to spring so i don't know much about creating persistence class).

My dispatcher class is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.roseindia" /> 

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass"

value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />

<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean> 

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_roseindia" />

<property name="username" value="root" />

<property name="password" value="" />       
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"     

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />     

<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
<value>net.roseindia.model.Article</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>

<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>                             
</props>
</property>

</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">

<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="articleService" class="net.roseindia.service.ArticleServiceImpl" ></bean>

<bean id="articleDao" class="net.roseindia.dao.ArticleDaoImpl"></bean>

</beans>
```

and article class is

```
package net.roseindia.model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "article")

public class Article {

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

@Column (name = "article_id")

private Long articleId;

@Column(name = "article_name", nullable = false, length=20)
private String articleName;

@Column(name = "article_desc", nullable = false)
private String articleDesc;

@Column(name = "date_added")
private Date addedDate;
```

i am getting the exception as :

```
12:18:17,226 ERROR [[dispatcher]] Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw  
exception
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: net.roseindia.model.Article
at     
org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:550)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1338)
at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:180)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState
(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:512)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.
performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:80)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.
onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:495)
at net.roseindia.dao.ArticleDaoImpl.saveArticle(ArticleDaoImpl.java:22)
at net.roseindia.service.ArticleServiceImpl.addArticle(ArticleServiceImpl.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.
invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
atorg.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.
invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
atorg.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.
proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.
invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation
.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.
invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy69.addArticle(Unknown Source)
at net.roseindia.controller.ArticleController.
saveArticle(ArticleController.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.
HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.
invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter
.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.
 AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.
doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.
doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.
invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.
invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.
invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.
invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.
process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.
run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

For complete code kindly visit [This link](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-and-hibernate3-example-part2.html)

You kind help and precious time in this regard will be appreciated.

Many many thanks in Advance..

Comment: can you post full stack trace.

Comment: @SubinS i have added the complete stack trace, kindly check it.

Comment: your setup seems fine for me. Are you getting any other exception when spring context is created , that is during the server startup.

Comment: @SubinS I don't get any other exception during the server startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually have a persistence.xml? Is your class listed in there?

```
<persistence-unit name="xyz">  
[...]
<class>net.roseindia.model.Article</class>
[...]
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: dear Korgen, actually there is no persistence. XML in the project, Is it necessary to add persistence. XML or we can manage without persistence. XML.